# CURLOPT_INTERFACE not working in php

Tags: php, curl

I am not able to bind to my ip addresses that are set in my network interface

The following command works
    curl --interface 41.141.41.23 https://www.google.com

but `$toSet[CURLOPT_INTERFACE] = "41.141.41.23 ";` in php doesn't work and throw `bind failed with errno 22: Invalid argument`

I am sure that `$toSet[CURLOPT_INTERFACE] = "41.141.41.23 ";` is the correct way to use multiple address in my application as i have confirm with the coder and many people are using it the same way as well without any issue

My curl version is : curl 7.19.7

Comment: Did you see this comment? http://php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php#75693

Answer (score 0):

"41.141.41.23 " =>  "41.141.41.23"
There is a space;